# How to get conversation list between two user in MongooseJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

i'm new to MongoDB and trying to build a simple chat app using Node.Js and MongoDB using mongoose Js. and i'm stuck here for last 2 days so need help!!
Tested most of the related answer of stack overflow but not getting desirable result.

What i want to achieve is something similar we see in chat application like Facebook Messenger and whatsApp web where in one side we see all our conversation list which show last message and person profile.

an example here http://roba.laborasyon.com/demos/dark/ (left sidebar)

this is how my model look like

```
const chat = new Schema({
    to:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"User",
        required:true,
    },
    from:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"User",
        required:true,
    },
    seenbySender:Boolean,
    seenByReceiver:Boolean,
    isFile:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    file:{
        type:Object,
        required:false,
    },
    text:String,
},{timestamps:true});
```

In My Controller or route file (this is not my code but i tried similar logic they all return empty array or error)

```
exports.test = (request,response,next) => {
    let {user} = request.body;
    const u=await User.findById(user);
    //Chat.find({from:user}).populate('from').populate('to').then(r => response.json(r));
    //user ="5f46319ac483a43d98ae3626";
    Chat.aggregate([
        {$match:{$or:[{"to":user},{"from":user}]}},
        {
            $group:{"_id":
                {
                    "text":{
                        $cond:[
                            {
                                $gt:[
                                    {$substr:["$to",0,1]},
                                    {$substr:["$from",0,1]}]
                            },
                            {$concat:["$to"," and ","$from"]},
                            {$concat:["$from"," and ","$to"]}
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "text":{$first:"$text"}
            }
        }]).then(result => {
        response.json(result)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("[[error]]",error)
        response.json({error})
    });
}
```

Here is data i'm working with (exported JSON file)

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f4a3ae0a7ff491f3024668e"
    },
    "isFile": false,
    "to": {
      "$oid": "5f46325ec483a43d98ae3627"
    },
    "from": {
      "$oid": "5f46319ac483a43d98ae3626"
    },
    "text": "Hi John,Yash here!",
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2020-08-29T11:24:16.416Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "$date": "2020-08-29T11:24:16.416Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f4a3affa7ff491f3024668f"
    },
    "isFile": false,
    "to": {
      "$oid": "5f46319ac483a43d98ae3626"
    },
    "from": {
      "$oid": "5f46325ec483a43d98ae3627"
    },
    "text": "hello Yash - John",
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2020-08-29T11:24:47.519Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "$date": "2020-08-29T11:24:47.519Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f4a3b25a7ff491f30246690"
    },
    "isFile": false,
    "to": {
      "$oid": "5f4632c8c483a43d98ae3628"
    },
    "from": {
      "$oid": "5f46319ac483a43d98ae3626"
    },
    "text": "Hello Don, Yash this side.",
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2020-08-29T11:25:25.067Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "$date": "2020-08-29T11:25:25.067Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

So what i need is last message of user he chatted with, with the user reference. in this case for Id: `5f46319ac483a43d98ae3626` the last 2 objects should be render

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: but why there is limit 2? the data i showed is just example of chat with 2 other user

Comment: you need last 2 objects right? can you add expected result as per that documents.

Comment: Actually the expected result is last two object if I'm logged in as "5f46319ac483a43d98ae3626"

Comment: can you look at this https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hzp79bQkPzs just updated link

Comment: thanks ,it's different but i can surely work with this, one more thing as you can see in my model   the to and from field is reference to user document so do i need to use populate? to get the user document along with

Comment: can you please show me how i can get whole user object instead of id! it will be very helpful.

Comment: somehow i achive this using lookup `{ $lookup: {from: 'users', localField: 'from', foreignField: '_id', as: 'from_user'} },` are there any better ways?

Comment: no, this is good way you can do it with lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `$split` to get limited records,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "to": ObjectId("5f46319ac483a43d98ae3626") },
        { "from": ObjectId("5f46319ac483a43d98ae3626") }
      ]
    }
  },
  // for descending order
  { $sort: { updatedAt: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$to", ObjectId("5f46319ac483a43d98ae3626")] },
          { $concat: [{ $toString: "$to" }, " and ", { $toString: "$from" }] },
          { $concat: [{ $toString: "$from" }, " and ", { $toString: "$to" }] }
        ]
      },
      updatedAt: { $first: "$updatedAt" },
      // push messages
      messages: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  // order by descending order
  { $sort: { updatedAt: -1 } },
  // limit to 2 messages only
  { $addFields: { messages: { $slice: ["$messages", 2] } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hzp79bQkPzs)

for joining user data you can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use this schema for a chat

```
   MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      from: {
        type: string,
        required: true,
      },
      to: {
        type: string,
        required: true,
      },
      time: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now(),
      },
      message: {
        type: string,
        required: true,
      },
    });


ChatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        firstUserId:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
        },
        secondUserId:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
        },
        Chat: MessageSchema,
})
```

and data will be as this way

```
[
  {
    firstUserId: "hjakdsf323275lks",
    secondUserId: "asdfe2342232aas",
    Chat: [
      {
        from: "hjakdsf323275lks",
        to: "asdfe2342232aas",
        time: "18/7/2020 20:06:09",
        message: "Hi ",
      },
      {
        from: "asdfe2342232aas",
        to: "hjakdsf323275lks",
        time: "18/7/2020 21:07:09",
        message: "hello ",
      },....
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good alternative but i think we can achieve the result with the schema i mentioned.